# Character Pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void){

  char *p = "Hello";  
  p = "Bye";              //Why is this valid C code? Why no derefencing operator?

  int *z;
  int x;
  *z = x
  z* = 2                 //Works
  z  = 2                 //Doesn't Work, Why does it work with characters?

 char *str[2] = {"Hello","Good Bye"};

 print("%s", str[1]);      //Prints Good-Bye.     WHY no derefrencing operator?
                          // Why is this valid C code? If I created an array with pointers
                         // shouldn't the element print the memory address and not the string?
  return 0;

  }
```

My Questions are outlined with the comments. In gerneal I'm having trouble understanding character arrays and pointers. Specifically why I can acess them without the derefrencing operator.

Comment: For str[1], dereferencing happens. Internally it will work like *(str + 1)

Comment: Coming to p = "Bye"  actually p is pointer to constant so if you do like *p = 'a'; it will not allow you at the time of compilation but since you did p = "Bye" , it will give a new address to p so it will work

Comment: @user93353. I did buy a book. This code came from a book. Thanks for your insightful comments. NOT

Comment: And the book had no explanation on what's going on?

Comment: You need to buy a better book - Maybe Kernighan and Ritchie? Maybe one of these - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693210/best-book-to-learn-c-from-the-beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type "Bye", you are actually creating what is called a [String Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Its a **special case**, but essentially, when you do

```
p = "Bye";
```

What you are doing is assigning the **address** of this String literal to `p`(the string itself is stored by the compiler in a implementation dependant way (I think) ). Technically address to the first element of a char array, as Richard J. Ross III explains.

Since it is a special case, it does not work with other types.

By the way, you should likely get a **compiler warning** for lines like `char *p = "Hello";`. You should be required to define them as `const char *p = "Hello";` since **modifying them is undefined** as the link explains.

---

As to the printing code.

```
print("%s", str[1]);
```

This **doesnt need a dereferencing operation**, since internally **`%s` requires a pointer**(specifically `char *`) to be passed, thus the dereferencing is done by `printf`. You can test this by passing a value when printf is expecting a pointer. You *should* get a runtime crash when it tries to dereference it.

Comment: You aren't storing the address of the literal itself - you are (in almost all recent compilers) storing the address of the first element in a statically allocated null terminated character array. There's no such thing as a string literal outside of the compiler itself.

Comment: So if I'm assigning the address of the string literal, why does it still not require * when printing the contents of that address?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII very true, but the difference is small enough, that I feel my version might be more understandable to new comers.

Comment: @Vlad: You don't need a * because the printf %s specifier knows it's supposed to get a pointer to a char.

Comment: I understand that it is the first element of a null terminated character array, honestly the syntax is what is confusing me.

Comment: @Bob Murphy, Thank you! That is an answer I was looking for. Makes sense.

Comment: @Vlad I answered your question in the 2nd half of my question.

Comment: @Karthik T, I appreciate that as well. Sorry I'm trying to read and process all answers and comments.

Comment: "You should be required to define them as" Nope. Only in C++. Not C.

Comment: "Since it is a special case, it does not work with other types." *What* exactly "does not work with other types"? The only thing specific to chars here is the fact that a string literal represents a char array. The assignment of an array to a pointer works for all types. If you are talking about the string literal, what would a "string literal" for other types even mean?

Answer (score 2):

> In gerneal I'm having trouble understanding character arrays and pointers.

This is very common for beginning C programmers. I had the same confusion back about 1985.

```
p = "Bye";
```

Since p is declared to be char*, p is simply a variable that contains a memory address of a char. The assignment above sets the value of p to be the address of the first char of the constant string "Bye", in other words the address of the letter "B".

```
z  = 2
```

z is declared to be char*, so the only thing you can assign to it is the memory address of a char. You can't assign 2 to z, because 2 isn't the address of a char, it's a constant integer value.

```
print("%s", str[1]);
```

In this case, str is defined to be an array of two char* variables. In your print statement, you're printing the second of those, which is the address of the first character in the string "Good Bye".

Comment: So if I am printing the address of the first character in the string "Good Bye", why does Good bye print? That's the part that is confusing me.

Comment: @Vlad: The %s specifier doesn't just look at the first character ('G'). It keeps printing characters in the memory addresses after that ('o', then 'o', etc.). It stops when it sees a memory address whose contents are the byte value 0 (zero), indicating the end of the text string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 p = "Bye";
```

Is an assignment of the **address** of the literal to the pointer.

The

```
array[n]
```

operator works in a similar way as a dereferrence of the pointer "array" increased by n. It is not the same, but it works that way.

Comment: "address of the literal" actually the address of the first element of the literal

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `"Hello"`, `"Bye"` all are `char *` not `char`.
So the line, `p="Bye";` means that pointer p is pointing to a `const char *`i.e."Bye"
But in the next case with `int *`
`*z=2` means that

> `int` pointed by `z` is assigned a value of 2

while, `z=2` means the pointer `z` points to the same `int`, pointed by `2`.But, `2` is not a `int pointer` to point other `int`s.So, the compiler flags the error

Comment: "all are char *" technically, they are char arrays, not pointers.

Comment: char arrays, OK but they can also be represented as char *

Comment: an array expression can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, yes

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing something: It does work with characters just as it works with integers et cetera.

What it *doesn't* work with are strings, because they are character *arrays* and arrays can only be stored in a variable using the address of their first element.

Later on, you've created an array of character pointers, or *an array of strings*. That means very simply that the first element of that array is a string, the second is also a string. When it comes to the printing part, you're using the second element of the array. So, unsurprisingly, the second string is printed.

If you look at it this way, you'll see that the syntax is consistent.

Comment: "arrays can only be stored in a variable using the address of their first element." No, you can have a variable of array type.